# Changing order of features in shapefile

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, sorting

I have a shapefile and I want to change the order of the features.

Is that possible?

I want to sort the features in the shapefile because I'm embedding this shapefile in a mobile app. The app will display a list of features, and although I could do the sorting at load time, I'd prefer to have them sorted.

Comment: Please only ask about one or other of QGIS and ArcMap within a single question.

Comment: @PolyGeo I don't agree with your comment (and closing the question). The question is about one (very specific) problem not a tool, and I don't want to prejudge which tool is best for solving the issue. During 11 years, there have been valuable answers using different tools. I don't think there is any rule to discuss either ArcMap or QGIS exclusively. I ask you to reopen the question.

Comment: GIS SE is a Question & Answer database compilation effort. The answers should reflect a solution in the requested platform, otherwise there's no basis for voting between two completely different answers. Not specifying a platform is, in effect, asking multiple questions, which *is* forbidden by the One question per Question policy.

Comment: @tato If asked today I would expect this question to receive 5 quick close votes for lacking focus. The site has evolved a lot in 11 years and it is today’s voting norms which are applied to all posts so that future posters see as many good examples of how to ask a focused question as possible. Closing does not prevent your question from continuing to receive upvotes if people think it is useful or downvotes if they think the opposite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always open the attribute table in ArcMap and right click the columns header and select Sort Ascending.../Descending... for single fields.

For multiple fields you would instead click Advanced Sorting to select multiple fields.

NOTE: Adding, for instance, a sequential ID field based on the current sorting (which is temporary, stored only in this map/mxd) when using the above method will be ordered by the original OID/ObjectID of the feature class.

There is an ArcScripts available that will sort records permanently and output a new shapefile: http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16771

I do hope that when you state 'order of features' that this is the order found in the attribute table and not drawing order for the table of contents/symbology levels.

Answer (score 17):

For QGIS there is a Sort plugin: http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Here is a solution to rewrite a new and sorted shapefile using the GDAL/OGR command-line tool [`ogr2ogr`](http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).

For example, a shapefile `orig.shp` has a numeric field `volume` to sort on. This particular SQL statement does a reverse sort (with `DESC`) so that features with large `volume` values are drawn before (underneath) features with small values:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM orig ORDER BY volume DESC" sorted.shp orig.shp
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [**Sort**](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm) in the (Data Management toolbox) which:

> Reorders, in ascending or descending order, records in a feature class
> or table based on one or multiple fields. The reordered result is
> written to a new dataset.

Answer (score 4):

An utility software of MapServer (free and open-source) can sort shapes according to attributes values :

http://mapserver.org/utilities/sortshp.html

Answer (score 2):

(In QGIS 3.12.3) Ensure you have the correct layer highlighted in the `Layers` panel, then search for **sort** in `Processing > Toolbox`. The tool is called `Vector general > Order by expression`. Choose an attribute column (aka. field) or expression to sort by and click <kbd>Run</kbd>:

[image: Partial screenshot showing relevant QGIS UI]

Answer (score 1):

A very, very FAST and easy method to sort a shapefile layer( using various fields) .

1 - Export shapefile to CSV (select good separator, like semicolon) and add GEOMETRY using "layer options" ->  "AS WKT"

[image]

2 - Open file.csv with LIBREOFFICE (calc) and use MENU->DATA->SORT (very intuitive, powerfull and VERY FAST (Sort on the fly 50000 features using 3 columns like sort-key, ascending and descending options, and i have a very slow notebook ;) )

3 - Save again file from LIBREOFFICE (calc) as "Text CSV" ( mark "Edit filter settings" and choose separator as 'semicolon', don't matter warning from libreoffice, save like CSV and select 'semicolon' as separator )

4 - From Qgis open the new file.csv (and sorted) from 'Add Layer" menu -> Add Delimiter Text Layer.

PROS:
- Very,very fast, sort from various fields
- Works ok with UTF_8 encoded data

CONS:
  - Need LIBREOFFICE (but is it open source software)

Alternative method to sort (sustitute points 2 and 3, and is the most fast) using console (BASH)

- Open console and go where you have file.csv

  Suppose you want sort file  with the key:

  field6(desc)+field1(ascen)+field3(desce)

  so the command will be:

  sort -t';' -k6,6r -k1,1 -k3,3r file.csv > file_sort.csv

  NOTES:

  - you can add -kn,n for every column  number 'n' (field) you needed add to your "sort key"
  - adding 'r' after every n,n will sort in reverse mode (descent)
  - Must pass the  character separator used into csv file with -t param