# Permanently Re-arrange fields of attribute table (feature class and tables)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, fields-attributes

I am trying to Find out simple Geoprocessing Tool that can physically re-arrange the fields of attribute table (for both feature class +  tables), I have found some posts here, but nether of them have provide a good and a simple tool that can do the  job.

Comment: Just as I was about to flag as a duplicate... You can also see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5873/permanently-reorder-fields-in-data-shp-gdb which has some further options.

Comment: There are several posts that address your question.  If you are unsatisfied with the answers, the preferred procedure is to start a bounty on one of the other duplicates.