# How to sort a column in attribute table programmatically

Tags: qgis, python, attribute-table, sorting

Is there any way to sort ( alphabetically ) a column in the attribute table programmatically (without clicking on the column header) in QGIS ?

Comment: I'm sure you can but are you aware that the _Attribute Table_ will ALWAYS be saved in ascending order of the _Field number_ regardless if you sort it by any other column?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5839/how-to-change-the-order-of-features-in-a-shapefile