# Is it possible to move one feature in front of another in the same layer?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is it possible to move feature in front of another? If I have smaller polygon and I draw larger polygon over it, is there a way how to move the smaller one in front? Is it possible in QGIS or better in PyQGis?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the data source format, since this strongly influences the options.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no option to change the Z order. AFAIK the elements are displayed in the order in the data source. So you can try to sort the elements by area e.g. order by clause in PostGIS, there is a sort plugin for shapefile in QGIS see:
[How to change the order of features in a shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5839/how-to-change-the-order-of-features-in-a-shapefile)
Another chance to separate the elements into two or more layers and set the right layer order in legend.

Answer (score -2):

There isn't a move to front feature but if you go to the item list in the item tab, you can move the layers up or down the list to change the Z order.

Comment: Does this work for features in the same layer?