# Advanced Sorting in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sorting

Can someone explain how to do advanced sorting of an attribute table using QGIS?. Every time I try to sort by script, it does not give me what I need and I don't know if there is any plugin that can do that.

Comment: For QGIS < 3.0, the [Sort and Number](https://github.com/ArMoraer/QGISSortAndNumber) plugin might answer your need. Check also this question: [Is there a way to assign row number for sorted table by column in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/192048/64955)

Comment: what type of sorting do you want?

Comment: it is a bit useful

Comment: I need to sort columns that contains numbers by ascending, Sort and Number plugin did not give me much of what I need