# Automatic numbering of attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a shapefile containing population data for Baltic countries. Using the SQL formula: $rownum in the field calculator, I was able to create an automatic numbering of rows (far right on the picture below), from 1 to the end of my table. However, for no apparent reason, the numbering is broken at row 129 and switches to 766. It changed at the exact place where I have a new country, so maybe it is linked.

Any reason why this happens?

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the source format of the data table. If it is a database, please specify which one (name and version).

Comment: As far as I can see your table is sorted by country, but the ids re generated in the order of storing. Try to sort table by the unique id, I suppose there will be no break. The code page of the table is not correct, you can change it in the properties of the layer, on the source tab.

Comment: If @Zoltan suggestion does not solve it, you can take a look into the .dbf file with e.g. libre office calc and check whether there is something wrong or missing.

Comment: since you are working with a sorted table, try this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192048/is-there-a-way-to-assign-row-number-for-sorted-table-by-column-in-qgis