# Adding descending row number using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm adding an id in QGIS with the function @row_number and it is adding the numbers descending, as you see it in the picture. But i need them exactly in the reverse order.

[image]

Comment: What if you use `$id`?

Comment: Without a sort order, the generated numbers should be assumed to be in a random order. For an ordered assignation, see this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/360357/84870)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a formula like

```
TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_RECORD - @row_number
```

(you may adjust result by adding a -1 or +1 depending if you want to start from 0 or 1)

You may also want to have a look at the [Sort and Number plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QGISSortAndNumber-master/)  :

> This plugin adds a new field to an attribute table, where features are
> numbered depending on multiple sorting criteria.

Comment: the plugin works fine, thx