# Group by unique value then count number of elements then list them

Tags: qgis

In QGIS3+ Field Calculator I am trying to group features by unique values in field 1 then assign a number (no matter the order) from 1 to *n* (*n*=number of elements grouped for each unique value in field 1) to populate field 2. The result should be something like:

```
feature field1  field2
1   Andree  1
2   Andree  2  
3   Andree  3
4   Luka    1
5   Luka    2
```

Sounds pretty simple to me and I know how I would it in R, for example. But I really cannot think about a way to do it in QGIS expression builder and without using CASE WHEN-like expressions for every value in field 1; though there are different questions (among others, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69986264/qgis-3-22-aggregate-elements-from-the-same-layer) or [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192048/assigning-row-number-for-sorted-table-by-column-in-qgis)) that I guess point to the right direction (using aggregation and arrays), I really don't grasp how to:

- Access/group by every value in field 1
- Assign a unique value to every feature from an array-type list

There are a couple of doubts above, but I'm looking for an answer to my first query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this expression (you could also replace `$id` with `feature` in your case as this field apparently is also kind of an `id`):

```
array_find (
    array_agg( $id, group_by:=field1),
    $id
)+1
```

[image]

Comment: In `array_agg` you can additionally `order_by` a second field